# css not class select?

Tags: css

Theres a mistake in my rather large demo where i assume all the divs under the class special will be used to align something. Now i realize i need to add an extra div outside of the part i want to align but inside of `.special`.

How do i write .special div[NOT someclass] ? or is there no way to do this and i need to rewrite a lot of html?

Comment: What browsers do you need to be compatible with? What about IE6 for example? It will directly affect how complex the solution will be

Answer (score 8):

CSS3 includes the `not()` selector. The only problem is (you guessed it) no IE compatibility. If you're willing to require Javascript from IE <9 users, you can get IE compatibility with IE9.js.

Answer (score 5):

+1 to both answers above.
I'll add i was able to get away with some things but writing this in the css block to undo the effect

```
some-type: inherit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with jQuery or some other Javascript Framework, the selectors just rock and NOT class XY is rather easy to achieve.
As Pekka pointed out I am not sure what brothers you want to target. getElementsByClassName() is implemented by almost all browsers (you know which one doesn't work, don't you?).

I found a rather nifty [solution on devshed](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/javascript-get-all-elements-of-class-abc-24349.html) to also make it work in IE:

```
onload=function(){
if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
    {
        var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:$|\\s)");
        var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var results = [];

        var element;
        for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
            var elementClass = element.className;
            if (elementClass && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
                results.push(element);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
}
```

All you need to do now is to iterate through all your div classes and negate the one you DON'T want.

Comment: Hehe... "I am not sure what brothers you want to target". I'd give you a humor upvote if such a thing existed :)

Comment: `typeof x == 'undefined'` is better than `x == undefined` because `undefined` is just a global variable that can be set to anything, but `typeof` is a keyword that always returns the correct string.

Comment: @Šime whoops... I'll leave it as it is for future fun @casablanca I always went with the latter, but your explanation tells me there is a better way. Thanks!